# Initializing an array from serverless.yaml and calling it from the handler

Tags: serverless-framework

I have an array in my handler that looks like this

```
process_list = [ 'Terminate', 'Launch', 'ScheduledActions', 'AlarmNotification' ]
```

I want to be able to set them in `serverless.yaml`

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

serverles.yaml

```
environment:
    MY_LIST: "foo,bar"
```

handler.py

```
my_list = os.environ['MY_LIST'].split(",")
```